# Анимация :leave не работает при *ngif = false в angular5

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frontend, angular5, angular

Всем привет)
искал по сети так и не нашел ответа.
Есть анимация в angular 5:

```
animations: [
    trigger('slideIn', [
      state('in', style({transform: 'translateX(0)'})),
      transition('void => *', [
        style({transform: 'translateX(-100%)'}),
        animate(1500)
      ]),
      transition('* => void', [
        animate(1500, style({transform: 'translateX(100%)'}))
      ])
    ])

 ]
```

И есть некий:

```
<div class="row"   *ngIf = "name === 'good mood'" >
  <div  [@slideIn]   class="col-md-3" *ngFor="let image of images.slice(0,4); let i = index;"   >
    <div >
      <div>
        <img  src="{{  image.url   }}" >
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

name - это переменная инпута что было введено.
При *ngIf === false анимация "входа" элемента работает правильно но "ухода" не работает. Знаю что при ngif удаляется дом элемент, но читал на пабликах что анимация ухода должна работать.
Спасибо всем.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно  [@slideIn]  переместить вверх *ngIf

```
<div class="row"  [@slideIn]  *ngIf = "name === 'good mood'" >

  <div class="col-md-3" *ngFor="let image of images.slice(0,4); let i = index;"   >
    <div>
      <div>
      {{i+1}}  <img  src="{{  image.url   }}"   >
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```